# Support Motoman Yaskawa gp-7 model

Tags: ros, motoman-driver, motoman, ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Created a package for the new robot to the driver motoman_driver. Uploaded INIT_ROS.JBI and MotoROSYRC1000.out in the robot controller. When you connect ROS to the controller, you receive the error message **Failed to find parameter topic_list**.
When trying to convey the position of the robot via actionlib get the same error message the **Joint trajectory action failing on invalid joint** and nothing happens.
What am I doing wrong?

```
[ERROR] [1506939087.527665396]: Failed to find topic_list parameter
[ERROR] [1506939087.537058139]: Failed to find topic_list parameter
[ERROR] [1506939092.711826118]: Joint trajectory action failing on invalid joint
```

If you run the test script move_to_joint.py from motoman_driver occurs transmission error **Unable to move to commanded position. Aborting.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272045/support-motoman-yaskawa-gp-7-model/) by [JADJER](https://answers.ros.org/users/32096/jadjer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2017-10-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-02**:
Please do not post screenshots for what is essentially text. Copy-paste the console output into your question, select it and press the *Preformatted Text* button (the one with `101010` on it), or `ctrl+k`.

Thanks.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-02**:
And please: in case of errors and warnings, include some of the lines above and below (if any) the error/warning text. Without context things are hard to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Created a package for the new robot to the driver motoman_driver.

I'm not sure I understand completely what you mean with this, but from the error you quote it would appear that the configuration on the ROS side is incomplete.

It's underdocumented (and I've logged [ros-industrial/motoman#180](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/issues/180) because of that), but for a single group robot, you should set the `controller_joint_names` parameter. This is mentioned in the [Using the Motoman FS/DX ROS Interface](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Tutorials/Usage) tutorial, in the *Joint Naming* section.

As an example, see the [joint_names_mh5.yaml](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/blob/d5e1bff4370d14345b5a72b6bfe0cb0eb4391124/motoman_mh5_support/config/joint_names_mh5.yaml) file in the `motoman_mh5_support` package. Such a yaml file typically gets loaded by the launch file that launches the driver launch file (such as [launch/robot_interface_streaming_mh5.launch](https://github.com/ros-industrial/motoman/blob/2a42b9d5c24f1336127a75e239ac0878d7d46e1e/motoman_mh5_support/launch/robot_interface_streaming_mh5.launch#L17)).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-02**:
Note that for multi-group setups the procedure (and configuration) is slightly different: [Creating a Dual-Arm System](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20Dual-Arm%20System).

**Comment by [JADJER](https://answers.ros.org/users/32096/jadjer/) on 2017-10-02**:
I changed `controller_joint_names to ['joint_s', 'joint_l', 'joint_u', 'joint_r', 'joint_b', 'joint_t']`
by analogy with motoman_mh5

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-02**:
And did you get it to work with that?

**Comment by [JADJER](https://answers.ros.org/users/32096/jadjer/) on 2017-10-02**:
Yes, it works, thanks for the help!